# Connecting to MySQL server computer

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I can connect to MySQL database that is running on the server computer using  localhost with this

```
connectionstring = "Host=localhost; database=dbname; user=dbuser; password=dbpassword;"
```

But I can't connect to this database from another computer using the host's IP address or the default database address (127.0.0.1).
This is the connection string to connect to the host computer

```
connectionstring = "Host=192.168.0.122; Port=3306; database=dbname; user=dbuser; password=dbpassword;"
```

I get this error;

> cannot connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

All privileges are enabled on the database and both computers are on the same network.
What do I have to do to connect to the database from another computer? Please help!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 == localhost, so it's quite obvious you can't connect to a remote machine using this ip address. Does the dbserver have a firewall? If yes, is port 3306 allowed for incoming connections? What is the value of `bind-address` in your mysql configuaration?

Comment: @derpirscher I have checked the my.ini file and it doesn't have the bind-address line. How do check if port 3306 is allowed for incoming connections?